# Dont allow update on empty textbox in php

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible not to update mysql data if one of the textbox in an html form which will update the mysql data is empty?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=form+validation and then come with specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($_POST['nameOfTheTextBox'])) {
    // do sql update query
} else {
    echo "you need to enter a text";
}
```

Also as the comment to your question proposes I would strongly recommend to read about form validation/sanitizing